# Pandas read DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to learn Pandas but I have a very basic question. 
When I try to read a csv file it gives me the file description but I cant display the data. Am i doing something wrong? It works with smaller files but with this one I don't know how to read  data. Here is my code:

```
   file =  pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\djimenez\\Desktop\\123.csv')
   print file
```

And this is what i get back

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 914 entries, 0 to 913
Data columns (total 2 columns):
dasz_id            914  non-null values
dasz_undev_2012    914  non-null values
dtypes: int64(2)
```

Iit seems that it is reading the data but I can't see it. How do I make a dataframe from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is limiting the number of rows to display, you can change this:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)
```

would fix that, there is a little about this [online](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html)

alternatively you can either print the dataframe: `print(file)` or just display the top `n` rows:

```
file.head() # default is 5 but you can pass any number
```

If you are in IPython then tab-completion will display the default and current settings:

> Available options:
>
> - display.[chop_threshold, colheader_justify, column_space, date_dayfirst,   date_yearfirst, encoding, expand_frame_repr,
>     float_format, height, large_repr,   line_width, max_columns,
>     max_colwidth, max_info_columns, max_info_rows,   max_rows,
>     max_seq_items, mpl_style, multi_sparse, notebook_repr_html,
>     pprint_nest_depth, precision, show_dimensions, width]
> - io.excel.xls.[writer]
> - io.excel.xlsm.[writer]
> - io.excel.xlsx.[writer]
> - io.hdf.[default_format, dropna_table]
> - mode.[chained_assignment, sim_interactive, use_inf_as_null]
>
> Parameters
>   ---------- pat : str
>       Regexp which should match a single option.
>       Note: partial matches are supported for convenience, but unless you use the
>       full option name (e.g. x.y.z.option_name), your code may break in future
>       versions if new options with similar names are introduced. value :
>       new value of option.
>
> Returns
>   ------- None
>
> Raises
>   ------ OptionError if no such option exists
>
> Notes
>   ----- The available options with its descriptions:
>
> display.line_width : [default: 80] [currently: 80]: int
>           Deprecated.
>           (Deprecated, use `display.width` instead.)
>
> display.max_columns : [default: 20] [currently: 20]: int
>           max_rows and max_columns are used in **repr**() methods to decide if
>           to_string() or info() is used to render an object to a string.  In case
>           python/IPython is running in a terminal this can be set to 0 and pandas
>           will correctly auto-detect the width the terminal and swap to a smaller
>           format in case all columns would not fit vertically. The IPython notebook,
>           IPython qtconsole, or IDLE do not run in a terminal and hence it is not
>           possible to do correct auto-detection.
>           'None' value means unlimited.
>
> display.max_colwidth : [default: 50] [currently: 50]: int
>           The maximum width in characters of a column in the repr of
>           a pandas data structure. When the column overflows, a "..."
>           placeholder is embedded in the output.
>
> display.max_info_columns : [default: 100] [currently: 100]: int
>           max_info_columns is used in DataFrame.info method to decide if
>           per column information will be printed.
>
> display.max_info_rows : [default: 1690785] [currently: 1690785]: int
>   or None
>           df.info() will usually show null-counts for each column.
>           For large frames this can be quite slow. max_info_rows and max_info_cols
>           limit this null check only to frames with smaller dimensions then specified.
>
> display.max_rows : [default: 60] [currently: 60]: int
>           This sets the maximum number of rows pandas should output when printing
>           out various output. For example, this value determines whether the repr()
>           for a dataframe prints out fully or just a summary repr.
>           'None' value means unlimited.

I've trimmed the output for brevity

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple, but i did not know what it was.

Comment: @DanielJimenez you can get a list of options even without IPython by doing `pd.describe_option()`, also you should have enough rep to upvote now ;)

Answer (score 0):

EdChum already gave a nice answer above, but an additional thing that I find useful is the to_clipboard() method on a dataframe which makes a copy of the frame that you can then paste into excel - I find this very convenient.  Before I noticed this method, I was often outputting a new csv every time I needed a quick look at a dataframe that was a bit big for an ipython viewer. (I would make this a comment to EdChum's answer, but my rep is < 50, so I cannot!)

In your case, that may not make sense since you could just open your csv directly in excel, but after a little processing on the frames you read in, it can be very useful.

Comment: Thanks, all the tips are very helpful. Like i say, I'm trying to learn how to use Pandas and the more info the better.